# Xcode Cloud Failing on Archive due to Swift Package

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package, xcode-cloud

I have a Swift Package ([GeoSwift](https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift)) that I’m including in a project I’m trying to set up with Xcode Cloud for a build / archive / release for Test Flight workflow.

When running that build I keep getting the error shown in the screenshot at the last step. Have tried the delete derived data / clean project / delete and re-add the Swift Package, but still keep getting this to happen.

[image]